# Keras Tensorflow custom layer only called once

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

After two days of intense searching, I did not find answers in keras docs/stack of.

I'm trying to create a custom layer to perform augmentation on each batch at some probability (now 1 for demonstration).
the data is an image with one channel.

I need a way to know if the augmentation actually happens while training because the prints inside the augmentation functions only happen once when the network is defined, and another when the `fit` function is activated.

any help will be much appreciated, Thanks!

Basic runnable working example, notice the number of prints from `call()` :

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers


# Custom Augmentation layer
class AugmentationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, p):
        super(AugmentationLayer, self).__init__()
        self.p = p

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        if not training:
            return inputs
        print('Enter Custom layer call, training = ', training)
        
        if random.random() < self.p:  
            inputs *= 2
        return inputs

# Training Script

# parameters
height = 38
width = 22
numClasses = 2
ydata = np.array([[1, 0], [1, 0]])   # hot-encoded labels

# create 2 images for network training data
Xdata = []
for i in range(2):
    xx = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (height, width))
    Xdata.append(xx)

# create array from list
Xdata = np.array(Xdata)

# make dims n_samples X height X width X channels = (2, 38, 22, 1)
Xdata = np.reshape(Xdata, (Xdata.shape[0], Xdata.shape[1], Xdata.shape[2], 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(height, width, 1)))
model.add(AugmentationLayer(1))                   # Added custom layer
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(numClasses, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001))

model.summary()

model.fit(
    Xdata,
    ydata,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=2,
    verbose=1)
```

Comment: The layers are called **once** to build the computation graph that is created by TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `tf.print()` it will print when running in graph execution as well. You can read more about it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! when i used tf.print() the message was printed to the standard output when i expected it to be - at each batch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for someone in the future, i will add that when compiling the model, there is a default value that prevents certain function to run from inside the custom layers (that's why regular print() did not work), for performance purposes. amongst them are: print(), np.save() and probably more.

```
model.compile(..., run_eagerly=False)   # default
```

if you want to enable all the function mentioned above, compile your model with:

```
model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)
```